# Inserting existing table in a float

Tags: tables, floats, lyx

I have a lyx file with tables which are not in a table float, I need to put them in a new table float . It seems it is impossible to do this in the GUI of lyx, So what are the workarounds to achieve this?

Comment: So you have a lot of `tabular`s, but none of them are inside a `table` environment.  Your question is how to insert the `tabular` inside the `table` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the "table" (which as Mario points out is a `tabular`), and go to

> Insert > Float > Table

For reference purposes, you might (patch pending) be able to run the following from the command buffer (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>) in `LyX 2.1` to do all of them at once.

```
inset-forall Tabular command-sequence char-forward-select; float-insert table
```

Comment: alt+ x is not working in my beta lyx 2.1 nor is the above command

Comment: @lyx101 alt+x should open a small text area at the bottom of your LyX window. If it does not work, go to `View > Toolbars > Command buffer`. The command will not work because this feature is not implemented yet. I posted the patch [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.devel/148770) and hope to commit it soon enough for `LyX 2.1 beta 2`. Note that the same command will work for many other insets (e.g. Graphics, Note), but just not Tabular yet.